# Is It Possible To Reference Flex Libraries Without Building Them Into The Flex 4 Project?

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, flash, external

Is it possible to build a flex 4 application that references or uses the flex 4 libraries (or any libraries that are compatible) without the project compiling them into the main SWF of the project.

So in a nut shell, I have a project and I want to load the flex 4 library from the server, is this possible? I've seen articles on compiler settings. Could this be the solution to loading the library from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible and advised !

- Right click on your project -> **Properties**
- **Flex Build Path** -> **Library Path**
- Set Framework Linkage to **Runtime Shared Library** (or expand each .swc and configure the linkage type).
- Expand each Flex framework SWC and Edit Linkage Type
- Click **Add**... and add both **swf** and **swz** versions of the library, example :

> ```
> framework_4.0.x.xxx.swf
> framework_4.0.x.xxx.swz
> ```

SWZ is an Adobe **signed version** of the library which can be stored in the Flash Player and is not subject to browsers cache purges. 
You have to allow your webserver to serve .SWZ files, so add a mimetype **application/x-swz** or **application/x-shockwave-flash** in your Apache/IIS.

The SWF version is used for failover, but will be purged in case the user clean his cache.

You'll find the .swz and .swf files in your bin-debug/bin-release after a build.